# conversion of datetime to getdate

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a problem in converting a column with datetime and need to convert into getdate.

For example column A (datetime, null) and that column contains value some right values with getdate and some values have something like this '1900-01-01 15:32:00.000'. I need help in changing the values to regular getdate values. And some fields in that columns has NULLS also.

Thanks in Advance,
Shashra

Comment: What should the value of 1900-01-01 15:32:00.000 actually be? GetDate() is a non-deterministic function which returns the current date/time according to the system.

Comment: "Getdate" is not the name of a format or a data type, rather the name of a function which returns the time at which it was invoked, every time it's called. So, what do you mean "convert into getdate"?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Set all dates that are `1900-01-01` to the current date and time? Ignoring `NULLS` and any other dates?

Comment: Please show the current format and the desired format.

Comment: What do you mean by "regular getdate values"?. GETDATE() is a function that returns the date and time of the moment it is executed.

Comment: Do you mean you think "1900-01-01 15:32:00.000" is wrong, and you'd like "2010-12-27 16:22:08.873"?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I need the current date/time system value..

Comment: Hi need the output like this '2010-12-08 16:15:31.973'... thanks

Comment: instead of this value 1900-01-01 15:32:00.000 I need the value like this which is current sys date/time value 2010-12-27 16:22:08.873

Comment: Shashra: please re-edit your question to include these comments you made answering us, to make the question clearer. Else it's very confusing until you look at all the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

GetDate() is a function that returns the current date and time. Yes, it includes the current time.

The example you provide looks like a 'pure' time (i.e. no date component available). If that is real data, then somehow you're getting decimal values of the form 0.#### recorded in that field. Of course, you could have real data from that date or you might have just invented that example for this question.

Finally, if you what you really want is to get rid of the time component so that you have a 'pure' date, try convert(datetime,convert(nvarchar(50),getdate(),101)). The inner convert creates text in the form mm/dd/yyyy and the outer convert turns that back into a date of the form yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 1):

- You wouldn't store the output of GETDATE() if you want it to be different every time.
  You'd do `SELECT col1, col1, GETDATE() AS Now FROM Mytable...`
- There is no safe way to distinguish a "real" vakes from a "false" value without having an arbritrary condition such as "anything on the last month is OK". "1900-01-01 15:32:00.000" is a valid datetime value

If you mean "ignore values where only a time bit, not date (01 jan 1900) then what about:

```
SELECT 
  col1, col2, 
  CASE WHEN DateTimeCol <> '1900-01-01 15:32:00.000' THEN DateTimeCol ELSE GETDATE() END,
  CASE WHEN DateTimeCol > '1901-01-01' THEN DateTimeCol ELSE GETDATE() END,
  ...
```